# EF Core Migration (code first): How do I add a new non-null column and populate existing records with unique values not based on data in other fields?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I currently have an entity:

[image: Customer entity before migration]

I want to add a field/column that will be non-null, and I want to populate each record with a unique value (a GUID, for example):

[image: Customer entity after migration]

My quandary is how to populate **existing** rows with data that will meet the UNIQUE constraint. I could perform one of the following migrations, but they both populate all existing rows with the same GUID:

```cs
// OPTION 1

//  Uses same GUID for all rows
migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
    name: "PublicId",
    table: "Customers",
    nullable: false,
    defaultValue: Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
    name: "IX_Customers_PublicId",
    table: "Customers",
    column: "PublicId",
    unique: true);
```

```cs
// OPTION 2

migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
    name: "PublicId",
    table: "Customers",
    nullable: false,
    defaultValue: "");

//  Still uses same GUID for all rows
migrationBuilder.Sql($"UPDATE Customers SET PublicId = '{Guid.NewGuid()}' WHERE PublicId = ''");

migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
    name: "IX_Customers_PublicId",
    table: "Customers",
    column: "PublicId",
    unique: true);
```

Is it possible to do something in a migration that populates each existing row with a unique value?

In case it matters, the database under the hood is SQLite.

---

**UPDATE**

I just used GUIDs as an example. In my case, it is another application function that generates the unique ID for this new field/column.

In other words, I cannot defer to the database (e.g., `NEWID()`) to generate the unique ID for me.

Comment: "EF Core Migration (code first): How do I add a new non-null column and populate existing records with unique values not based on data in other fields?" - **with difficulty** (real-talk: EF migrations really don't work well for anything beyond trivial additive changes, eventually they start being a huge burden to maintain and work-around and eventually you'll just disable them and apply schema changes by-hand)

Comment: Option 2 is fine,  but you need use the SGBD instruction to generate a new GUID for each row.

Comment: With SQL Server : `migrationBuilder.Sql($"UPDATE Customers SET PublicId = NEWID() WHERE PublicId = ''");`

Comment: @vernou, forgive me: I am not familiar with "the SGBD instruction," and a quick web search was no help.

Additionally, my database is not SQL Server; it is SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `defaultValueSql` to set a custom SQL expression and `newid()` as expression (for SQL Server).

```
migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
  name: "PublicId",
  table: "Customers",
  nullable: false,
  defaultValueSql: "newid()");
```

There should be something similar for Sqlite.

Comment: alas, this will not work in my case. (I used a GUID as an example.) In my case, the unique ID is generated with an application function—nothing that the database has access to.

Comment: In that case I think that it cannot be done using a migration. You shoud add the column as nullable, fill it with the data you need and eventually alter the column to not nullable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add it as nullable, have your application set the id, then later change it to non null.

As to whether you can do that all during a single EF Core "ApplyMigrations()" process - I suspect you can if determined enough. For example, here is one way of doing it off the top of my head if you were applying migrations using EF Core in app:

1. Add two migrations, the first one adds the nullable column - make a note of its "MigrationId". The second one is empty, get its migration id also.

```
// check to see if we need to apply this migration - it may have been applied already on a previous app startup.

 var pendingMigrations = await dbContext.Database.GetPendingMigrationsAsync();
 var applyFirstMigration = IsMigrationIdPending(pendingMigrations, "Your-Migration-Id-That-Adds-Nullable-Column");

// Note that DbContext.Migrate() builds on top of the `IMigrator` service, which can be used for more advanced scenarios. 

var migrator = myDbContext.GetInfrastructure().GetService<IMigrator>();

if(applyFirstMigration)
{
// apply the migrations only up to the one that adds the nullable column
await migrator.MigrateAsync("Your-Migration-Id-That-Adds-Nullable-Column", CancellationToken);

}

var applySecondMigration = IsMigrationIdPending(pendingMigrations, "Your-Migration-Id-That-Does-Nothing");

if(applySecondMigration)
{
// use whatever foo you need to set these records in the database to values provided here by your application - this could be executing a script via ado net, another dbcontext, this dbontext (not sure whether that will work), or even - passing the ids statically (static property) on your "empty" ef core migration, and have that ef core migration generate SQL to execute when it is applied etc)
await UpdateRecordsWithNull();
await migrator.MigrateAsync("Your-Migration-Id-That-Does-Nothing", CancellationToken); // makes sure this migration is applied so we won't ever run this step again.

}
```